# openid attribute exchange

Tags: openid, attributes

I'm trying to use JanRain openid, I've already added some of the required fields like email, nickname etc.. and some optional fields, but the openid provider doesn't send me back any information except the user's openid url.

I'm trying on localhost.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to provide some more information about what you're doing on localhost. Are you running an OpenID server on localhost to be your own OP (OpenID Provider?)

Comment: i'm working with openid consumer, trying to do with attribute exchange to get some information of user from provider, but it's not work, yahoo provider said: 

"This website does not meet Yahoo!'s requirements for website address"

and when i move my consumer on my hosting with real domain, it's said about claiming, so i need to contact yahoo provider or other provider to put my website on white  list ?

Comment: It seems like you were trying to use the OpenID 1.x protocol with Yahoo, which won't work. Do you have the latest version of the JanRain library?

Comment: i using 2.xx version, the login processing work well, just a problems with attribute exchange, some website like verisign attribute exchange work, but on yahoo, google, it say something about i must contact them, and do something blah blah... which i dont know

Answer (score 4):

Not every OpenID Provider would be able to reply for all your attribute requests since they might not have those information. Ever OpenID Provider specifies the attributes that they support for attribute exchange.

for example : Google supports only 5 attributes: firstname, lastname, email, language and country. You can find more info [here](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html#Parameters).